# Continuous integration & eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, continuous-integration, hudson

I am developing a set of eclipse plugins, and I have several JUnit plugin tests that actually start another instance of eclipse, create a mock workspace and a mock project and runs various operations on them. I want to put that on continuous integration and I am at loss as to where to start. I am using Hudson, would there be any plugins that makes that easier? Can those tests launch eclipse in headless mode or something on the CI server? Pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was trying to do that about 6 months ago, but hadn't enough time. You are going into the right direction. You need to start a headless eclipse and run the right ant target. You ran the headless eclipse by calling the runAnt script in the bin directory. There is a way to find the available ant target from with in the eclipse ide. If you checkout the workspace for the first time from your scm, you might need to run the importproject target first to load the project folder into an eclipse workspace. Since Google wasn't too helpful for me, please document your solution here.

Comment: I was looking into this aswell some time ago, I got as far as getting the JUnit plugintests to run from commandline;

java -jar eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar -configuration build/configuration -DjavacSource=1.5 -DjavacTarget=1.5 -DjavacFailOnError=true -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -file test.xml

I was hoping that would be enought to integrate it into hudson, but havent had a chance to test it yet. Please update when you get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution for building Eclipse-based software currently is Tycho - it is based on Maven and uses your standard Eclipse files (like manifest, target platform, product definition). I got started with it using an intro from this blog: http://mattiasholmqvist.se/2010/02/building-with-tycho-part-1-osgi-bundles/, and it worked really well. We also use Hudson, and since Tycho is Maven-based, Hudson integration was trivial and worked simply by calling Maven, which Hudson supports out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [Buckminster](http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/) tries to solve these problems: you can create descriptors, and then Buckminster can execute your tasks.

For Hudson there is a Buckminster module, that helps executing the Buckminster builds.

Comment: I'm using Buckminster with Jenkins and it works like a charm. It may be a little difficult to set up (depending on your environment), but just a little.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you to avoid plugin tests? ;) i like to avoid them... by using mock objects...

http://blog.srvme.de/2010/12/10/mock-eclipse-ifile/